# Python Pandas DataFrame Meessage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

please how can I replace this message with my own?

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Airline, Destination, Passengers]
Index: []
```

Comment: you should create a child class from DataFrame and overwrite __rpr__ method

Comment: do you actually want to **replace** the message or **test** for an empty dataframe ?

Comment: I actually want to replace the message with mine

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite `__repr__` method:

```
class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.empty:
            return 'some stuff'
        else:
            return super().__repr__()

# print(MyDataFrame())
# some stuff
```